# How to derive headers from a list of data based off a where clause and a subquery

Tags: mysql, date, subquery, unix-timestamp

I am trying to generate a list derived from two tables.  The end result should be:

```
Date     A    OHS     OMSN    OMSS
date1    1     1        2       3
date2    4     5        6       7
date...   ..    ..      ..      ..
```

The date ranges are generated off of a calendare table I generated and are being right joined so they are included even if the count for the other buildings are 0.  Under each building there is a count that should simply count the workorders for each day.  Here is the query I have so far:

```
Select calendar.datefield As 'Date',
  Count(FROM_UNIXTIME(workorders.dateSubmitted, '%Y-%m-%d')) As 'Count'
From workorders Right Join
  calendar On (FROM_UNIXTIME(workorders.dateSubmitted, '%Y-%m-%d') =
      calendar.datefield)
Where calendar.datefield Between '2011-08-30' And date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
Group By calendar.datefield
```

This query gives me the total workorders for all locations for each day on a specific range.  Including this is fine but I want to have 3 more columns that are filtered by each specific loction.  If I add the building name like this:

```
Select calendar.datefield As 'Date', workorders.location,
  Count(FROM_UNIXTIME(workorders.dateSubmitted, '%Y-%m-%d')) As 'Count'
From workorders Right Join
  calendar On (FROM_UNIXTIME(workorders.dateSubmitted, '%Y-%m-%d') =
      calendar.datefield)
Where calendar.datefield Between '2011-08-30' And date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
Group By calendar.datefield, workorders.location
```

Then the table gives me the data i need but not the columns I am looking for.  The data will be somethine lie this:

```
2011-09-08  OHS     27
2011-09-09  OHS     24
2011-09-10  NULL    0
2011-09-11  NULL    0
2011-09-12  OHS     23
2011-09-13  OHS     18
2011-09-13  OMS-N   1
2011-09-14  OHS     20
```

I want to pull from this query by selecting the date, then the numbers where it is OHS, then the numbers where it is OMSN, then the numbers where it is OMSS etc...

There has to be an easier way to do this and I have literally worked tall day trying to piece this query together.

I hope someone can help.  I learned mysql on the fly over the past few months and any help is much appreciated.

_*_* FURTHER REVIEW:

```
SELECT calendar.datefield, tOHS.Count AS 'OHS'
FROM calendar
LEFT JOIN (
SELTCT workorders.school, Count( workorders.dateSubmitted ) AS 'Count', FROM_UNIXTIME( workorders.dateSubmitted, '%Y-%m-%d' ) AS test
FROM workorders
RIGHT JOIN calendar ON ( FROM_UNIXTIME( workorders.dateSubmitted, '%Y-%m-%d' ) = calendar.datefield )
WHERE calendar.datefield
BETWEEN '2011-08-30'
AND date_format( now( ) , '%Y-%m-%d' )
AND School = 'OHS'
GROUP BY calendar.datefield, workorders.school
)tOHS ON calendar.datefield = tOHS.test
WHERE calendar.datefield
BETWEEN '2011-08-30'
AND date_format( now( ) , '%Y-%m-%d' )
```

This returns the dates and the daily count for the first location OHS.  WHEN I try this:

```
select calendar.datefield, tOHS.Count as 'OHS'
from calendar
LEFT JOIN 
(
Select workorders.school, Count(workorders.dateSubmitted) As 'Count', FROM_UNIXTIME(workorders.dateSubmitted, '%Y-%m-%d') as test
        From workorders Right Join
      calendar On (FROM_UNIXTIME(workorders.dateSubmitted, '%Y-%m-%d') =
          calendar.datefield)
    Where calendar.datefield Between '2011-08-30' And date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d') AND School = 'OHS'
    Group By calendar.datefield,workorders.school
    ) tOHS
 on calendar.datefield = tOHS.test
 LEFT JOIN
 (
Select workorders.school, Count(workorders.dateSubmitted) As 'Count', FROM_UNIXTIME(workorders.dateSubmitted, '%Y-%m-%d') as test
        From workorders Right Join
      calendar On (FROM_UNIXTIME(workorders.dateSubmitted, '%Y-%m-%d') =
          calendar.datefield)
    Where calendar.datefield Between '2011-08-30' And date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d') AND School = 'OMS-S'
    Group By calendar.datefield,workorders.school
    ) tOMSS
 on calendar.datefield = tOHS.test
 WHERE calendar.datefield Between '2011-08-30' And date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

It breaks the query all together.  I see the same date and the same value repeated for all columns.  Am I using the wrong join?

Comment: Upon further review I was able to generate something close to what I am looking for using a join that is joining a subquery with the filter in it.  The problem is when I try to make a second join it royally messes up the query. - Appended to end of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of research and rethinking I determined how to do this.  Basically, we need to be selecting each field (calendar.datefield, the count for location 1, the count for locaiton 2, the count for location 3...)

To get the count I did a LEFT OUTER JOIN of the subquery that is right joined to the calendar.  This makes the subquery return the count for each individual day (grouped by each calendar day) and this gets left outer joined (as mentioned a few seconds ago) to the calendar.datefield which is then filtered by the where clause between dates a and b.

Then rinse and repeat that left outer join of each subquery.  I am not an SQL master and I never went to school for this so it may not be optimized or perfect but it works and works fairly quickly.  I am just glad to have figured it out.

```
    select calendar.datefield, (ifnull(tOHS.Count,0)+ifnull(tOMSS.Count,0)+ifnull(tOMSN.Count,0)) as 'Total', ifnull(tOHS.Count,0) as 'OHS', ifnull(tOMSS.Count,0) as 'OMS-S', ifnull(tOMSN.Count,0) as 'OMS-N'
from calendar

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
Select workorders.school, Count(workorders.dateSubmitted) As 'Count', FROM_UNIXTIME(workorders.dateSubmitted, '%Y-%m-%d') as 'Date'
        From workorders Right Join
      calendar On (FROM_UNIXTIME(workorders.dateSubmitted, '%Y-%m-%d') =
          calendar.datefield)
    Where School = 'OHS'
    Group By calendar.datefield,workorders.school
    ) tOHS
 on calendar.datefield = tOHS.Date

 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
Select workorders.school, Count(workorders.dateSubmitted) As 'Count', FROM_UNIXTIME(workorders.dateSubmitted, '%Y-%m-%d') as 'Date'
        From workorders Right Join
      calendar On (FROM_UNIXTIME(workorders.dateSubmitted, '%Y-%m-%d') =
          calendar.datefield)
    Where School = 'OMS-S'
    Group By calendar.datefield,workorders.school
    ) tOMSS
 on calendar.datefield = tOMSS.Date

 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
Select workorders.school, Count(workorders.dateSubmitted) As 'Count', FROM_UNIXTIME(workorders.dateSubmitted, '%Y-%m-%d') as 'Date'
        From workorders Right Join
      calendar On (FROM_UNIXTIME(workorders.dateSubmitted, '%Y-%m-%d') =
          calendar.datefield)
    Where School = 'OMS-N'
    Group By calendar.datefield,workorders.school
    ) tOMSN
 on calendar.datefield = tOMSN.Date


 WHERE calendar.datefield Between '2011-08-30' And date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

This returns dates from range a to b and gives total for 3 buildings and each building.  I have 4 buildings but it is easy to add as many as you want by copy and pasting each LEFT OUTER JOIN down to the on clause and changing the variables then adding a new select for that count.

Wow this stuff can get confusing.  hope it helps someone someday :-)

Bil